# Webview in an Applet not working from a self signed jar

Tags: java, webview, applet, javafx

I have made an app using Java FX and [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html). Everything works fine when deployed as an application in a standalone jar. When I try to integrate the same as a [browser embedded application](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deploy_overview.htm#CEGHEAHD) (applet), I can see the interface which I've developed, but no URL is loading.

After googling, I came to know (from the [JavaFX deployment documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deploy_overview.htm#CEGJGHDA)) that I have to sign my application. I did self sign my application and tried to run it. But it still did not work.

Do I have to obtain a secure certificate for running WebView in browser?

This browser embedded application is for internal usage and not for wide distribution.

Comment: anyone who knows the solution please help me...